# Remove ' from cell, but keep cell content as text

Tags: excel

I am looking to remove the ' before the content of a cell in order to do a VLookup, whowever when there are no letters it is turning the value into a number and the vlookup is retrieving inaccurate values. Any idea?

pre  - '02364W105
post - 02364W105

pre  - '151290889
post -  151290889 (this becomes 1.51E+08)

Answer (score 0):

Change the cell format to `Numbers` and it does change the style. Normally it should work without it though.

Comment: After changing the format to `number` enter a number of 20 digits, What does it show up?

Comment: The leading ' is removed via a right function, as a result the remaining information in the cell is transformed into text. So it is strange this is happening.

Comment: @GowthamShiva It cuts the number after 15 digits but show the full number in the cell. didnt realize that.

Comment: @Lowpar Excel does not really differ between string(that only contain numbers) and numbers as values of cells. it will convert them automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You ha ve to select all these cells and change format to *Number*.

Probably they will still include the " ' " until you edit each one from the formula bar or pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> and then <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

The best way to avoid editing one by one is to write "1" into an empy cell, then copy it, then select all the cells you want to convert to number, then paste special, select "values" and "multiply".
This will convert all you cells with number formatted as text into numeric cells with numbers inside.